# motion artifact removal in ppg signal with python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I studied some papers and I saw that we can remove the artifact from `ppg` by wavelet and `threshold` the coefficients of it. I wrote the code, but the code doesn't have any effect on the input signal. I used the threshold from (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1746809419302058). I want to apply a threshold to coefficient1to3. The threshold is different for coefficients due to the deviation in magnitude.
'''

```
coeff = pywt.wavedec(filterd2, wavelet='db4', level=3)
final_y=[]

for k in range(1, 4):
    temp = np.zeros(coeff[k].shape)
    for i in range(0,len(coeff[k])): 
        # print(f'gama={gamaathresh},alpha={alpha}')
        sigma = (1/0.6745) * madev(coeff[k])
        alphathresh = sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.log(len(coeff[k])))
        gamaathresh=0.8*alphathresh
        alpha=-(1/gamaathresh)*(-0.95)
        if coeff[k][i]<=gamaathresh or coeff[k][i]>=(-gamaathresh) :
            # print(f'x<thresh= {x[i]}')
            #final_y.append(coeff[1])
            temp[i] = coeff[k][i]
        else:
            coeff[k][i]=(1-np.exp(-alpha*coeff[k][i]))/(1+np.exp(-alpha*coeff[k][i]))*alphathresh
            # print(f'x>thresh= {x[i]}')
            #final_y.append(coeff[1])
            temp[i] = coeff[k][i]
            # print(coeff[1].shape)
    final_y.append(temp)
print(size(final_y))
plt.plot(filterd2)
plt.show()
signal=pywt.waverec(final_y,wavelet='db4')
plt.plot(signal)
```

'''

[image]

Comment: Do you also have an accelerometer sensor? You can try to regress-out the acceleration data from the PPG signal. On the PPG signal alone, try maybe removing frequencies you are not interested with with IIR filter. Since you are using PPG, I guess you are interested in the heart rate, RR or something like that. Movements occur with different frequencies than heart activity related phenomena.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have accelerometer signals too.is there any source or paper that lead me how I can use accelermeter signals to remove artifact from ppg?